# Do we need to do multicollinearity check if we are building a lasso/ridge/Elastic net regression models?

Tags: regression, classification, multicollinearity, regularization, elastic-net

I have built an elastic net model for classification purpose, but I haven't done multi-collinearity check. Would doing multicollinearity check and then feeding the variables to the model have an effect on the accuracy of the model?

Comment: How would you react to detecting multicollinearity?

Comment: If elastic net doesn't take care of multi-collinearity then I would first do the vif test and remove the variables which are multi-collinear

Comment: How do you know that there's multicollinearity to be taken care of by the elastic net?

Comment: I don't know if elastic net takes care of it. That is the whole question! Does it take care? If not I will remove multi-collinearity